# Input fields & converting text to numeric

Tags: java, android, text, textfield

I have an app I am working on that does some math on a few variables and outputs the answer. Well that's the plan anyway. Being a total n00b at Android & Java I am not sure of a couple of things.

1) I have created text fields in the layout file for user to enter values. Instead of text fields should I use numerical value fields, if such a thing exists?

2) How can you convert from a text field to a numerical value and back again?

Many thanks for any help
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL )

or in the xml file we can set the property of the edittext field to android:numeric="integer|decimal".

Answer (score 1):

For converting from string to numerical value we can use: `Integer.parseInt( string_to_convert )`
e.g.

```
int your_variable1 = Integer.parseInt(str_to_be_converted1);
int your_variable2 = Integer.parseInt(str_to_be converted2);
```

Also, if you are calculating the area your piece of code can be like this:

```
int area = Integer.parseInt(length)*Integer.parseInt(breadth);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the edit text property to take only numbers. android:numeric="integer|decimal".

use textview widget to show the result and edittext widget to take the input.

Next get the content(edittextobject.getText())in the edittext fields and then convert the content to integer to operate .

convert the result back to string and call
textviewobject.setText(resultstring)

Comment: So if I enter the following code it limits my EditText pos1_deg to an integer:
pos1_deg.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

How can I get it to accept a floating point value?